# If $f$ is a entire function such that $f(z+n+im)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

**If $f$ is a entire function such that $f(z+n+im)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f$ is constant.**

I'm having trouble solving this one. Could you help me?

I have tried to get to that $f$ is bounded to apply the Liouville theorem, but I do not know how to limit this function, could someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: [Here $f$ is a doubly periodic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_periodic_function)

Comment: Hint: the closed unit square is compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(R)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb C$, where $R$ is the rectangle $\{a+bi\mid a, b\in[0, 1]\}$. Hence $f(R)$ is bounded. By that $f(z+n+im)=f(z)$, it follows that $f(\mathbb C)=f(R)$. Thus $f$ is a bounded entire function. Then the Liouville theorem entails that $f$ is constant.